# RadioGroup doesn't obey the constraints in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-radiogroup

I'm currently creating a form and i am using a constraint layout, with my elements linked in a vertical chain to spread them evenly. It works great with every type of XML element, except for the RadioGroup which is stuck to the top of the parent (the constraint layout) no matter what I do.

The constraints I set for it are correct, I tested them on a textview and it goes exactly where I want, so the problem comes from the RadioGroup.

Is it a well known issue that RadioGroups don't care about constraints? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: share a code please

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this problem as follows when I experienced the same problem: RadioGroup must have ID.

Comment: Could you expand a little on your answer to show how you assigned an ID to each RadioGroup, possibly with some code or XML markup?  As it is your answer looks a bit too much like a [me too answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252479/3744182) and so might get deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I have never experienced this problem myself. I tried to reproduce it by using two `TextView`s and a `RadioGroup` with three `RadioButton`s, but it worked as expected for every chain style (and worked regardless of ordering of the views).

[image]
[image]
[image]

*(From left to right: `spread`, `spread_inside`, and `packed`)*